# Chrome Native Messaging with electron app

Tags: google-chrome-extension, stdin, electron, stdio, chrome-native-messaging

I'm trying to set up communication between a chrome extension and an electron app on OSX.

I have the JSON file in `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/NativeMessagingHosts/com.company.app.json`

```json
    {
        "name": "com.company.app",
        "description": "MyApp",
        "path": "/Users/johnryan/Desktop/Code/electron-app/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar",
        "type": "stdio",
        "allowed_origins": ["chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
    }
```

On the chrome extension i have a simple native messaging call:

```js
    chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('com.company.app',
      { text: "Hello" },
      function(response) {
        console.log("Received " + response);
      });
```

then in the main.development.js i have:

```js
    var readline = require('readline');
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
      input: process.stdin,
      output: process.stdout,
      terminal: false
    });
    
    rl.on('line', function(line){
        console.log("RECEIVED:" + line);
    })
```

However, when i execute the `sendNativeMessage` I don't see anything in the logs. Is there something i'm missing here?

Comment: A guess: since the [message starts with a 32-bit binary length](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging#native-messaging-host-protocol) the first bytes are 0 for short messages so you should read in binary mode otherwise it might get interpreted as the standard end of string by readline.

Comment: @wOxxOm Interesting i'll give that a try. My guess was that there was something wrong on the electron side, the default_app.asar seemed fishy and in other examples it seemed to be pointing to a .js file. Not sure if that should matter though.

Comment: @john_ryan did you manage to accomplish this?

Comment: @jonathanwiesel not exactly, I ended up starting an http server inside the electron app then just posting to the local server

Comment: @john_ryan Did you use [electronify-server](https://github.com/eliquious/electronify-server) to spin up the local web server? If not, do you have some sample code you'd be willing to share of how you went about getting the local server running in electron to communicate with the Chrome extension?  Thanks.

Comment: @Corey that tool looks like it might be a good solution, i just used a regular express.js server and started it like this:
http.createServer(this.app).listen(port, 'localhost', () => {
      console.log(`server listening on port ${port}`);
 })
Then i was able to post to that port from the chrome extension on localhost.

Answer (score 4):

Recently stumbled upon this issue, and found out that in windows platform access to stdin and stdio from main thread is not supported.  Temporarily I have made it work by starting the http server inside my electron application and listening from http port in windows platform.

However the same should work on MAC OS just build your electron application using electron-packager and give path of your exe(exe of your electron app) in the path variable, as given below.

```json
    {
        "name": "com.company.app",
        "description": "MyApp",
        "path": "/Users/johnryan/Desktop/Code/electron-app/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.exe",
        "type": "stdio",
        "allowed_origins": ["chrome-extension://xxxxxxxxxxxx"]
    }
```

In order for it to work in windows see this post it might have a solution,

[GitHub -Issue of stdin and stdio in electron application](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4218)